How to add grid item titles for different media querys?
I have just learned how to use css grid. and I want to apply it on a certain case:
on large screen width, I want the following grid structure:
#  title1 title2 title3
1  val11  val12  val13
2  val21  val22  val23

on narrow screen width, I want the following grid structure:
# 1 
title1 val11
title2 val12
title3 val13

# 2 
title1 val21
title2 val22
title3 val23

I guess I can use a "full" grid, and display only parts of it on different media querys:
e.g.
#     title1(**)       title2(**)       title3(**)              
# 1   title1(*) val11  title2(*) val12  title3(*) val13
# 2   title1(*) val21  title2(*) val22  title3(*) val23


(*) hidden on large screen width
(**) hidden on narrow screen width

but is there a simpler way, without duplicating the title cells?

Existing solutions that "transform" table elements for a mobile view, often use pseudo elements to generate such repeated "heading" texts, https://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/

Is your data really tablular? If so, for accessibility purposes, you may like to switch to using table elements for the correct semantics. Also, as @CBroe suggests,  pseudo elements can help reduce repetition of the titles' texts, but again investigate possible accessibility issues.

... just found out that if an element is not assigned a explicit grid-area. the grid do keep an area for it, with additional gaps ... solution: all grid items should always be included in grid-area decleration. can use display:none to hide them

You can manage this with pseudo elements.
I have done a snippet adding a class to the grid for narrow or wide display.
You can adapt it to use media queries easily


.parent {
  display: grid;
  gap: 4px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  margin: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 150px);
  width: fit-content;
}

.parent.narrow {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 150px);
}

.child {
  height: 25px;
  display: grid;
}

.narrow .child {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 150px 150px;
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
}

.parent.wide .child:nth-child(-n+3) {
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 30px 30px;
}

.child:before {
  background-color: white;
}

.narrow div:nth-child(3n+1):before,
.parent div:nth-child(1):before {
  content: "title1";
}

.narrow div:nth-child(3n+2):before,
.parent div:nth-child(2):before {
  content: "title2";
}

.narrow div:nth-child(3n):before,
.parent div:nth-child(3):before {
  content: "title3";
}

.c1 {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.c2 {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.c3 {
  background-color: mistyrose;
}
<div class="parent narrow">
  <div class="child c1">Child 1</div>
  <div class="child c2">Child 2</div>
  <div class="child c3">Child 3</div>
  <div class="child c1">Child 1</div>
  <div class="child c2">Child 2</div>
  <div class="child c3">Child 3</div>
  <div class="child c1">Child 1</div>
  <div class="child c2">Child 2</div>
  <div class="child c3">Child 3</div>
</div>
<div class="parent wide">
  <div class="child c1">Child 1</div>
  <div class="child c2">Child 2</div>
  <div class="child c3">Child 3</div>
  <div class="child c1">Child 1</div>
  <div class="child c2">Child 2</div>
  <div class="child c3">Child 3</div>
  <div class="child c1">Child 1</div>
  <div class="child c2">Child 2</div>
  <div class="child c3">Child 3</div>
</div>



